# Fine tuning search

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-addin, search-scope

We (company wise) are using SP13. 
We have a document library containing information that should not be found when doing a search on the page - e.g. on the Home page using "Search entire site. I have set "Allow items from this list to appear in search results?" to No but it still shows results from all other pages. 
In general: what is the best way to fine tune a search on the site. 
Note: 
Usage of SharePoint Designer is disabled.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to accomplish. If you don't want the documents from that particular library to appear in ANY search results, then the setting you found "Allow items from this list to appear in search results" should work. Try running a Full Crawl of the content source as that setting does not take effect until you reindex that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Search service application -> Crawl rules -> Add the URL to library or folder that you wish to exclude from crawls.

You will find some help on how to do this on the "Add Crawl Rule" page, or you could take help from MSDN.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it resolves your issue, so that it doesn't appear among unanswered questions.